# bootstraping an angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm bootstrapping an angular app using code someone else wrote:

```
window.app = angular.module('angularYoApp', ['ui.router',]);

window.bootstrap = function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['angularYoApp']);
};

window.init = function(){
    window.bootstrap();
};

$(function(){
    if (window.location.hash == "#_=_") window.location.hash = "";  // ...

    window.init();
});
```

I have `html5Mode` set to true in my config:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`

Everything works fine, though I'm wondering, what is this line for:

`if (window.location.hash == "#_=_") window.location.hash = "";`

the comment isn't really helpful. Do I need it with html5Mode?

Answer (score 0):

That's for fix facebook redirect seems like it appends those chars to the url

html5 = false

```
if (window.location.hash === '#_=_') window.location.hash = '#!';
```

if you are using

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

in your case if you have html5  set to true

```
  if (window.location.hash == "#_=_") window.location.hash = "";
```

I think you'll need that in html5 anyway